# Trouble running hello world android app

Tags: android, sdk

I'm a newbie who installed Android studio but simply can't get a simple hello world app to run!

Whenever I try running a program, I get the error :

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

I've been googling but to no avail. I've changed build.gradle to :

```
defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.minimap.Minimap.minimap"
     minSdkVersion 8
     targetSdkVersion 8
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
}
```

and I added this to my manifest :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

Yet the hello world app fails to run on two different cellphones (a samsung galaxy s3, and an alcatel), so I'm guessing the problem is on android studio's side. I'd like to mention that I have not forgotten to install the API 8 sdk

Do you guys have any idea what might be going on? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you facing problem?In which device it is not running ?

Comment: You installed the SDK with the SDK Manager?

Comment: @Soham : I get the same error on both devices

Comment: @merkizniak what is your compileSdkVersion ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set your `targetSDKVersion` to 22 (The lastest Android revision).
It will let you use the latest library included in Android.

Also, on Android studio, using Gradle, you dont' have to add the `uses-sdk` tag in your Android Manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

It will be override during the build phase